# Transposing/Wrangling Database Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Firstly, transposing is too specific a word for the kind of transform I want to do. I have a software that allows a technician to design custom forms for end users. From the form, I can see every entry on it (checkbox, textbox) is stored in a row. I have been asked to report on these forms, and the only way I can think of to make the data more usable is to wrangle it into a new table where each row represents one form entry.

Before:

```
Entry    FormElement    Value
1        Checkbox1      True
1        Textbox1       Joe Smith
2        Checkbox1      False
2        Textbox1       Jane Johnson
```

After:

```
Entry    Name          isMale
1        Joe Smith     True
2        Jane Johnson  False
```

- Is there any other way to report on the data than what I am considering?
- Should I use a stored procedure?

Comment: How do you know that Checkbox1 ties to isMale? Since the users can create custom forms, what if Jane Johnson's question was "is allergic to peanuts?"

Comment: I just edited for clarity. I have access to the form, it was built by a tech. For the sake of brevity I just gave an abbreviated version of what's going on, there are dozens of fields.

Comment: A stored procedure is nothing magical, it's just going to be a collection of SQL statements crafted to solve the problem. If the question is the choice between a stored procedure to solve the problem and an SSIS package, what does your team best support? Even with the edit, I'm still unclear as to how you will know Checkbox1 translates to IsMale and Textbox1 is a name. You are familiar with your data domain and we are not.

Comment: A PIVOT statement will do this for you. There are many questions here on this subject, and many more examples throughout the web. The syntax can be a bit trickey to get right, so I'd suggest starting with a really cut-down example and then building it up once you've got the basics sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see with such a design is to self join the table several times. This means a JOIN for each column required in the output.

Notes:

- The sample used is available toward the end and in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86ac0/4/0).
- You will have to figure out what the value of `FormElement` means when writing the query
- An age value has been added to it (bigger sample).
- Expect bad performances with such a design on a large data set
- An index on `FormElement` and `Entry` including `Value` or filtered indexes on `FormElement` may help.
- It uses 1 subquery for each object because it helps see the separation between self joins.
- I suppose there is always a row for each object from the form (hence the `INNER JOIN`)
- I replace `isMale` by a `CASE` statement and Male or Female. It may help you.
- Views may help writing shorter queries if some combination are often used.

#### People between 30 and 40

For example, if you want people between 30 and 40:

```
SELECT name.Entry
    , Name = name.[Value]
    , Sex = CASE WHEN sex.[Value] = 'True' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END 
    , Age = age.[Value]
FROM (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Textbox1'
) name
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Checkbox1'
) sex 
    ON name.Entry = sex.Entry
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Textbox2'
) age
    ON name.Entry = age.Entry
WHERE age.[Value] > 30 AND age.[Value] < 40
;
```

Output:

```
Entry   Name        Sex     Age
1       Joe Smith   Male    32
3       Lucy Smith  Female  35
```

#### Name starting with a J

For people with a name with a J:

```
SELECT name.Entry
    , Name = name.[Value]
    , Sex = CASE WHEN sex.[Value] = 'True' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END 
    , Age = age.[Value]
FROM (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Textbox1'
) name
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Checkbox1'
) sex 
    ON name.Entry = sex.Entry
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Entry], [Value] FROM data WHERE [FormElement] = 'Textbox2'
) age
    ON name.Entry = age.Entry
WHERE name.[Value] LIKE 'j%'
;
```

Output:

```
Entry   Name            Sex     Age
1       Joe Smith       Male    32
2       Jane Johnson    Female  25
```

#### Sample data used

```
CREATE TABLE data
    ([Entry] int, [FormElement] varchar(9), [Value] varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO data
    ([Entry], [FormElement], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'Checkbox1', 'True'),
    (1, 'Textbox1', 'Joe Smith'),
    (1, 'Textbox2', '32'),
    (2, 'Checkbox1', 'False'),
    (2, 'Textbox1', 'Jane Johnson'),
    (2, 'Textbox2', '25'),
    (3, 'Checkbox1', 'False'),
    (3, 'Textbox1', 'Lucy Smith'),
    (3, 'Textbox2', '35')
;
```